# Is my Jquery lost?

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        if (window.jQuery) {

            alert($(".Dollar").html());
        } else {
            // jQuery is not loaded
            alert("Doesn't Work");
        }
    }
    alert($(".Dollar").html());
</script>
```

For some reason the first alert works and the second crashes.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined MyPage:50 (anonymous
>   function)

Comment: You didn't include jQuery !

Comment: Post your <head> section or doublecheck if you included jQuery: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

Comment: jQuery isn't the only library that uses `$`, and jQuery being included in the page doesn't guarantee that both `$` and `jQuery` are the same thing.

Comment: @KevinB Too right, the first time I found out about this was after several hours of confused debugging before finding out that WordPress's `enqueue_script` function doesn't allow for shorthand `$` notation (for reasons beyond me).

Comment: @Pinch: Which alert works, and which alert fails? Does the alert inside the window.onload-function fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

was declared at the end (footer) of my default template page.

I was calling JQuery before its scripts were rendered.

`window.onload` waits to the complete page is loaded, despite poor script positioning.

Thats why the first  `alert($(".Dollar").html());` worked.

But to throw out an `alert($(".Dollar").html());` before Jquery is rendered!

Thanks to everyone who pointed me in the right direction! and to KevinB for giving SO integrity!

Comment: If this answers your question, can you select it as the answer? and possibly explain why it fixes your problem?

Comment: @KevinB, pending one day to select as answer. Because I was calling JQuery before its scripts were rendered as they were at the footer of the page in my default template.

Answer (score 2):

This is because, window.onload is run after the dom has loaded (and your jquery script file has been loaded). The second alert($...) is run immediately, before the browser had time to load the jquery script.

Comment: the reasoning here doesn't sound right at all.. The error is originating from the alert inside the window load event.

Comment: The jquery import can be placed anywhere in the dom, and the first alert will work. The second alert though would require the jquery import to happen before that script block is hit.

Comment: jQuery is loaded synchronously unless something else for some strange reason was added to the script tag, so this is just all wrong. The document ready handler is for the DOM to be ready, not for jQuery to be loaded, that will happen on the next line when it's loading synchronously.

Comment: Right, but look at last part of that error. *"(anonymous function)"* the error is being thrown after the window load event, not before. That means jquery IS included initially, but then overridden or $.noConflict after.

Comment: The question said the second alert din't work. I assumed second as in, second in the code posted.

Comment: window.onload is only fired after the entire window is loaded ( scripts, css, images etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you are not loading another library that is overwriting the `$` global variable.

Comment: I wish this answer were worded as an answer rather than a question. It is most likely the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are getting suggests that some time between that piece of code and the onload event you are using $.noConflict. It could look something like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        if (window.jQuery) {

            alert($(".Dollar").html());
        } else {
            // jQuery is not loaded
            alert("Doesn't Work");
        }
    }
    alert($(".Dollar").html());
</script>
<script src="someotherlibrary.js"></script>
```

where `someotherlibrary.js` has this somewhere inside:

```
var someVar = $.noConflict();
```

What's happening is you're binding to the onload event, then firing off the alert at the bottom of the script tag, which doesn't error because `$ === jQuery`, however, the next script that gets included causes `$ === undefined`, causing the onload handler to fail. A quick test to prove this would be to simply replace `alert($(".Dollar").html());` with `alert(jQuery(".Dollar").html());` inside the onload handler.

Answer (score 0):

As vishahvkt already said, the onload-event will be triggerd after the whole DOM (inclusive JQuery) loaded completly.

The alert outside the onload-function will be executed as soon as it has been loaded.

So, when this alert is being processed, JQuery might not be ready yet. And even if it is: Your element with the class `.Dollar` won't exist yet (Assuming that it is below you script-tag).

Try creating a second script tag, at the end of your page, and place your alert there. If this was the reason, it should work then.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. The error is coming from the alert that appears first in the code (clued in by the last part of the error message) which makes the reasoning in this answer fall apart.

Comment: "For some reason the first alert works and the second crashes." I assume that the second alert in the code is meant, isn't it? Why do you think the otherone is meant?

Comment: Because of the error message. *"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined MyPage:50 **(anonymous function)**"* the anonymous function part would instead say index or whatever the html page is named.

Comment: Furthermore - vishahvkt's answer says the same

Comment: It wouldn't say index. It isn't within a function, so it would also say **anonymous function**.

Comment: No it isn't, it's within a script tag, outside of the function. `alert(foo())` isn't an anonymous function.

Comment: Ok, after some tests, I have to admit that you're right. So I got a downvote, because the question can easily mislead someone :(

Comment: I'm sorry it turned out that way, all due to the OP miss-diagnosing the problem to begin with, :p I know you're just here to help. Don't take it personally, the downvote is there to rate the answer, not necessarily the person writing the answer. you were just miss-lead.

Comment: Yes, thats ok. If noone would downvote, wrong answers couldn't get identified. At least I learned something new - script-tags aren't automatically anonymous functions.

Comment: well... i did some testing too, and in jsfiddle with chrome, when i click the down arrow on the error, it does report "anonymous function". so... You may be right, depending on what browser is being used. There's just not enough provided in the question. When i use an anonymous function, i get anonymous function twice, and when i don't use an anonymous function, i only get it once. http://jsfiddle.net/uLyNN/ but it appears as though he has already somehow solved his problem.

Comment: I think this is the fault jsfiddle. If you don't use the html-window, and put `bar();` inside the script-window, it doesn't say anonymous function. Tested it with chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/M6S3f/